# Unable to delete data in Laravel 10

Tags: laravel, eloquent, crud

I'm trying to delete data in my Laravel project, but when I click on the Delete menu, it just shows the confirmation alert. After I click OK, it only refreshes the `/barang` page, which shows the records list in the `barang` table. And the item I wanted to delete is still there. What am I doing wrong?

`routes/web.php` :

```
Route::get('/barang', [BarangController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/barang/create', [BarangController::class, 'create']);
Route::post('/barang/create', [BarangController::class, 'store']);
Route::get('/barang/{barang:slug}/edit', [BarangController::class, 'edit']);
Route::put('/barang/{barang:slug}/edit', [BarangController::class, 'update']);
Route::delete('/barang/{barang:slug}', [BarangController::class, 'destroy']);
```

`BarangController.php` :

```
    public function destroy(Barang $barang)
    {
        Barang::destroy($barang->id);

        return redirect('/barang')->with('barangSuccess', 'Data Barang berhasil dihapus');
    }
```

`views/barang/index.blade.php` :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <form action="/barang/{{ $row->slug }}" method="POST">
            @method('delete')
            @csrf
            <a class="dropdown-item" href=""
                onclick="return confirm('Data will be deleted. Continue?')">
                <i class="bi bi-trash"></i> Hapus
            </a>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `<a` does not submit a form, a submit button/input would

Comment: I'd suggest giving your Route names, like `Route::delete('/barang/{barang:slug}', [BarangController::class, 'destroy'])->name('barang.delete')`, then using `<form action="{{ route('barang.delete', $row->slug) }}">`. Also, all this `<a>` element is doing when clicked is `return confirm(...)`, but you're not doing anything with said confirm, and you don't have an `href`, so it'll just reload the page...

Comment: You'd need to change this to a `<button type="submit">` (or similar), or handle the click of this `<a>` _properly_, i.e. by adding `href="#"`, triggering the submit of the form if `confirm()` is `true`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form action, make sure you are using the correct URL. You need to include the actual id of the barang item in the URL.                      `<form action="/barang/{{ $row->slug }}" method="POST">`
Replace this line with:

```
<form action="{{ url('/barang', $row->slug) }}" method="POST">
```

This ensures that the form action points to the correct URL with the 'id' parameter.

Confirmation Dialog:
Ensure that the confirmation dialog properly triggers the form submission. You can use the submit method to trigger the form submission programmatically.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="confirmDelete('{{ $row->slug }}')">
    <i class="bi bi-trash"></i> Hapus
</a>

<script>
    function confirmDelete(slug) {
        if (confirm('Data will be deleted. Continue?')) {
            document.getElementById('delete-form-' + slug).submit();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you

**Controller**

```html
public function destroy(Barang $barang)
{
    // Data validation
    if (!$barang) {
        return redirect('/barang')->with('barangError', 'Data barang tidak ditemukan');
    }

    // Delete data
    Barang::destroy($barang->id);

    // Redirect to barang page
    return redirect('/barang')->with('barangSuccess', 'Data barang berhasil dihapus');
}
```

With this validation, you can ensure that the barang data you want to delete actually exists in the database. If the data does not exist, an error message will be displayed.

**View**

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <form action="/barang/{{ $row->slug }}" method="delete">
            @method('delete')
            @csrf
            <a class="dropdown-item" href=""
                onclick="return confirm('Data will be deleted. Continue?')">
                <i class="bi bi-trash"></i> Delete
            </a>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Form doesn't even submit, so validation won't help. There is no `method="delete"` for forms.